# Will Formiks getfieldprops , Form , Field , FieldArray will work with reactnative

Tags: react-native, forms, performance, formik

While I try to handle onChange,HandleBlur opertaion using the getfieldprops of useFormik in react-native. I am struck with the below error image [image: getFiedProps Error]At the same time when I try to overcome this issue with Formik=>Form=>Field combo I am struck with different issue just like the below one [image: Form=>field combo] . I have attached both the scenario code below . My question is can we implement the form=>field and getfieldprops concept of formik in react-native. Any help will be appreciated.

```
**useFormik with getFieldProps code**

import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: '',
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log('Submit', values);
    },
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Input
        {...formik.getFieldProps('name')}
      />
      <Button onPress={formik.handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

**Formik=>Form=>Field combo code**

import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: '',
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log('Submit', values);
    },
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Input
        onChangeText={formik.handleChange('name')}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur('name')}
        value={formik.values.name}
      />
      <Button onPress={formik.handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: You can find all the examples here https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/tree/main/examples